# jqXHR.abort is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to do cancel button for jquery file upload (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

My code:

```
var jqXHR = $('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: 'server/index.php',
dataType: 'json',
dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
})

$('button.cancel').click(function (e) {
    jqXHR.abort();
    alert("cancel");
});
```

When I click on cancel button, the cancel button does not work and I am getting " jqXHR.abort is not a function" error.

What do I need to do to get cancel button to cancel file uploading working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the documentation, it should be done like this.

```
var jqXHR = null;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
    add: function (e, data) {
        jqXHR = data.submit();
    }
});
```

Now you can access the jqXHR object like this

```
$('button.cancel').click(function (e) {
    jqXHR.abort();
});
```

---

For multiple aborts, the method will be this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function(e, data) {
         $('.progress_bar_wrapper').append($('.progress_context:first').clone());
        data.context = $('.progress_context:last');
        data.content.find('.abort').click(abortUpload );
        var xhr = data.submit();
        data.context.data('data',{jqXHR: xhr}); // so much data...
    }
)};

function abortUpload (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var template = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.template-upload'),
     data = template.data('data') || {}; // data, data , data (queue Monty Python skit)
      if (!data.jqXHR) {
        data.errorThrown = 'abort';
        this._trigger('fail', e, data);
      } else {
        data.jqXHR.abort();
      }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/290

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after I add `jqXHR = data.submit();` into add section like your example, it bypass the image resize function. So, where should I put `jqXHR = data.submit();` if I want image resize function work?

Comment: Yes, but not working. It gives me `Error: cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'send'` message

Answer (score 2):

As the [document API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#how-to-cancel-an-upload) states, you should use the `send` method to get back the `jqXHR`. This would work for you

```
var jqXHR = $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {
    url: 'server/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
});

$('button.cancel').click(function (e) {
    jqXHR.abort();
    alert("cancel");
});
```